# setInterval() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, setinterval

I am trying to run a function at `setInterval()` of "1 second", but it is a bit problematic. I have done everything as shown [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) but it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
<script>
   function test(db_time)
   {
      var c_db_time= db_time/1000; 
      var current_time = new Date().getTime()/1000;
      return Math.round(current_time - c_db_time);
   }
   $(".elapsed_time").each(function() {
      var time_r = $(this).data('time_raw');
      var inter = $(this).html(time_ago(time_r));//parameter to function

      setInterval(inter,1000)
   });
</script>
```

And the error is :**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

---

**Solution found** thanks to @Bommox & @Satpal

```
 $(".elapsed_time").each(function() {
var time_r = $(this).data('time_raw');
    var self = $(this);
    var inter = function() {self.html(time_ago(time_r));}
    setInterval(inter, 1000);
  });
```

Comment: What is `inter`? a function? Can you post what you get in line `var inter = $(this).html(time_ago(time_r));`

Comment: @Satpal its the variable

Comment: setInterval accept only function

Comment: inter is not a function which is what setInterval expects.

Comment: $(this).html(time_ago(time_r)); what it returns it is wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said before, first argument should be the function:

```
 var self = $(this);
 var inter = function() {
     self.html(time_ago(time_r));
 }
 setInterval(inter, 1000);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work how you expect it to.  When the function is run, won't `this` refer to the window?

Comment: I'm not sure because you define function out of the setInterval. But now it's better, thanks!

Comment: @Bommox, I have edited your answer. If you feel my edit is incorrect Please feel free to rollback

Comment: It doesn't matter where you define the function, the variable `this` will always refer to calling function context (and can be changed by the caller)

Comment: The other thing you have to take into account is that the `time_r` variable might need to be re-read depending on how it is used

Answer (score 7):

into [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function's first parameter you should pass a function or an anonymous function like

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log("1s delayed")
},1000);
```

Comment: ok but now i get a new error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined `

Answer (score 0):

```
var self = this;
setInterval(function(){
     $(self).html(time_ago(time_r));
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here : [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

```
window.setTimeout( function() { /*your code which you want to execute after fixed interval, it can function name or lines of code*/}, /*fixedInterval*/);

window.setTimeout( function() { alert("Hello World!"); }, 5000); // it will execute after 5 seconds
```