# how to load a .each function on body load

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeago

based on my previous question ([HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495665/setinterval-not-working)) ive updated my time ago code block, it works fine,the interval gets called every 10 sec but im faced with yet another silly problem . **My problem** is that i dont know how to load the function as soon as the body is loaded

my code (the important part)

```
  $(".elapsed_time").each(function() {
     time_r = $(this).data('time_raw');
    var self = $(this);
    var inter = function() {self.html(time_ago(time_r));}
    setInterval(inter, 10000);
  });
```

Comment: @Unknown it not a possible duplicate besides ive tried the solutions on that question none work

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in jQuery by wrapping your code in the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //-- This code will run when the body is loaded
});
```

You can also use the shorthand notation to accomplish the same thing:

```
$(function () {
  //-- This code will run when the body is loaded
});
```

Edit:  Kevin raises a good point, this is technically different from a true 'body load' event. The way I interpreted your issue, you wanted to wait until all of the elements are available before running your code.

More info on this: [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/js-window-onload-vs-jquery-document-ready)

Comment: That will run before onload.

Comment: @sircapsalot They are the same. See here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @sircapsalot Yup! Which is pretty much why I'm on stack in the first place : )